# Disabling user-select doesn't work properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I tried disabling user-select in CSS for every element in every browser like this:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
  }
```

It works well in all browsers except Firefox.
In Firefox, everytime I click on the **background** of my page, everything becomes selected. This doesn't happen to any other element, just the background. I use some jQuery, but disabling it didn't help.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've finally solved it with a neat little jQuery UI function.

```
$('*').disableSelection();
```

It works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

Change your -moz- rule:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```